# How to re-base a forked repo when doing a merge request - Gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I forked a repository and made some changes locally. I committed those changes but now I want to merge those changes back into the upstream repo. I made a merge-request on Gitlab but it is failing. Apparently I need to rebase the forked repo.

- Does this mean there were new changes on the upstream repo?
- When I compared the branches before doing the merge request, why does it show no conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, what did you compare?
I guess you forked the repo, cloned your fork and then compared your local branch against your remote branch.
But if there were changes upstream, this is another kettle of fish.
Add the upstream repository as a second remote to your local repository with `git remote add ...` and fetch its changes, then you can compare all three, the upstream branches, your forks branches and your local branches against each other and also rebase your branches accordingly against upstream before creating your merge request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I imagine you want to merge some commits in one before Pull Request. If this is your question:

In your local repository:

`git rebase -i HEAD~n (n is the number or commits to be merged)`

Just after this the edit program will open to you "program" the actions

In the first n lines you inform the command you desire: probably in your case you place `squash` to merge commits. You can see a list of commands.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh9KtjfjzCU) you can see a good video explain step by step.

After that, just `git push`. If you pushed before merge the commits, use `git push --force`, but be sure what you are doing when use `--force`